# How can i filter a ManyToManyField if it contains a specified user?

Tags: python, django, filter, manytomanyfield

I have a model like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

And now in my view I want to filter so that the logged in user can se all Posts that the person follows. And the problem is that more people can follow the same Post.

```
def get_followed_posts(request):  
    user = request.user  
    posts = Post.objects.filter(followers__contains=user) # If the user is in the list of followers return the Post.
    return render_to_response('post_list.html', {'posts': posts}, context_instance=request_context(request))
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

You should be able to do do -

```
Post.objects.filter(followers__in=[user])
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I tried that earlier but it did not work for some reason. But when I tried again it did.